# Search column B for last two unempty field and get both of their column A counterparts

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wish to find the last two payments in Column B (but not always above each other) and then obtain the date that is in column A for those payments.  Then have the number of days between these payments shown in the top of Column B.

All information starts from row 10 downwards.

What formula could I use to get this information ?

Comment: Are the rows without payments blank, or zero?  Can you add an additional column?

Comment: Do the rows without payments still have a date?

Comment: The other rows in the column are blank, yes the other rows have dates that relate to other payment columns.  not sure about adding another column.  I am going to try the formula below and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is formatted as an Excel table, put this formula into B1 and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to make it a range formula.

```
=MAX(IF(Table1[Pmt]>0,Table1[Date]))-LARGE(IF(Table1[Pmt]>0,Table1[Date]),2)
```

You would obviously have to substitute the PMT and DATE entries to match the table column headings, and replace "Table1" with your actual table name.

Thanks to @simoco for the inspiration from [Given value in column A, find min/max in column B in EXCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383047/given-value-in-column-a-find-min-max-in-column-b-in-excel)

*EDIT*
To reference from a different sheet, and to not use a table:

```
=MAX(IF(Sheet1!$D:$D>0,Sheet1!$A:$A))-LARGE(IF(Sheet1!$D:$D>0,Sheet1!$A:$A),2)
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to make it a range formula.

Comment: I just tried this...

=MAX(IF(Sheet1[d:d]>0,Sheet1[a:a]))-LARGE(IF(Sheet1[d:d]>0,Sheet1[A:a]),2)

but it will not store the formula, it says something is wrong but does not say where or what.

Comment: how do I add a file here, I was just about to post the mockup excel I created based on my own file.

Comment: Two things:  (1) your missing the "!" character after the Sheet1, and (2) unless you're referencing an excel table, remove "[" and "]".  This works for me on Sheet3:  =MAX(IF(Sheet1!D:D>0,Sheet1!A:A))-LARGE(IF(Sheet1!D:D>0,Sheet1!A:A),2)   CTRL SHIFT ENTER

Comment: Given you mentioned that your data starts on row 10, there is a danger if rows 1 - 9 of column A contain a future date, as this would be picked up by the generic A:A reference.  If at all possible, look at converting the range to an excel table, which will let you use the first solution.

Comment: its still not working for me.  is there a file store or something i can post my file in for this site ?